# Qual o limite de argumentos do operador IN no SQL Server?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, operadores

No Oracle são 1000 argumentos, qual o limite no SQL Server?

Comment: Não sei o limite, mas a performance tende a ser muito prejudicada se a lista for longa.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo! Subselects são melhores nesses casos?

Comment: @Laerte você pode fazer com `INNER JOIN` se o resultado estiver em outra tabela

Comment: Aí tem que ver caso a caso, pode usar um subselect, e/ou uma tabela temporária.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe um limite estabelecido em documentação e não pude achar uma resposta que determine o tamanho exato, então podemos considerar que não há um limite específico.

Certamente não é ilimitado, mas o limite pode estar relacionado por outras coisas. Uma possibilidade é o tamanho do *batch* que é equivalente a 65536 pacotes de rede. Outro pode ser a quantidade de parâmetros da função. Mas não tenho certeza se isto se aplica. O tamanho de qualquer função é 2100 argumentos, conforme a documentação. É possível que mais algum limite exista.

Então ao contrário do Oracle, o SQL Server não tem essa limitação específica.

Se encontrar um limite, em algumas situações você ainda pode separar em mais de um `IN` e unir com um `OR`, se ainda for possível.

Se estiver usando muito pode estar fazendo algo errado.

[Documentação sobre limites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado bigown. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando uma *subquery* no `IN` cheguei ao limite de memória utilizado pelo banco, mas não no limite da cláusula. Utilizei o seguinte *script* para isso:

```
declare @numeros table(numero int);
declare @proximo int = 1;

set nocount on;

while @proximo < 100000
begin
  insert into @numeros values(@proximo);

  print @proximo;

  if @proximo % 100 = 0
  begin
    select 1
      where 1000000 in (select numero
                          from @numeros);
  end;

  set @proximo = @proximo + 1;
end;
```

Provavelmente declarando os elementos o limite seja o relatado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169945/qual-o-limite-de-argumentos-do-operador-in-no-sql-server/169946#169946) do [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown). No teste que realizei a *query* chegou tranquilamente a `999999` números comparados.

---

**EDIT**

Realizei também o seguinte teste para validar o limite de elementos e obtive o mesmo resultado do teste anterior:

```
declare @proximo int = 1,
        @in      varchar(max);

set nocount on;

while @proximo < 100000
begin
  set @in = isnull(@in + ',', '') + cast(@proximo as varchar);

  print @proximo;

  if @proximo % 100 = 0
  begin
    exec('select 1 where 1000000 in (' + @in + ')');
  end;

  set @proximo = @proximo + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Esse limite com o subSelect não existe mesmo no SQL-Server ou Oracle. O limite ocorre quando você elenca todos itens dessa maneira in ( 1,3,4,5,6...)

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo é, testei isso no segundo exemplo, não tem limite numérico mesmo...